# 10.15 Catalina - Not showing Sync Mark on Finder

Tags: mac, finder, catalina

As you can see in the screenshot, the files that are synced is not showing an icon indicating whether synced or not. It used to show different icons when syncing, and sync complete.

[image: desktop_image]

I believe it is set properly to show the icon.

Below is a screenshot from the setting page of Backup And Sync, the app that I am using to sync these files.

[image: sync_and_backup_setting_screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this particular problem by unticking "Show file sync status icons and right click menu" and reticking it. Open another Finder.